# Webview is not loading more data with loadUrl()

Tags: android, android-webview

I am using `webView` for loading Instagram url. The problem is that no more data is appended to the `webView` if I scroll down. The progress of loading new data is rotating forever without loading new data.

Here it is might the code of interest.

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Posting the screenshot of the problem.

Help will be appreciated. Thanks!

[image: here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangled the problem. The problem was that I had put the `WebView` in a `ScrollView`.

Comment: In my case when I only put `webview` it can load more data but when I put `webview` inside `scrollview` `webview` can't load more data.